# Send Null in http request

Tags: http

I am receiving a slightly peculiar request in my application. I need to replicate it in postman or some similar program but I don't know how to do it. The problem is that the request does not start with /xxx. This is the request captured in the tomcat log:

```
"GET null HTTP/1.1" 400 435 15
```

Thanks in advance.

Hi Antoniossss, I have tried with `http://targethost.com/null` but the request is not the same, now the log trace shows the /, and the response is not a Bad Request but a NotFound. I understand that the request must somehow not be well formed

```
"GET /null HTTP/1.1" 404 131 6
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46705090/strange-requests-in-access-logs-lead-to-illegalargumentexception for a similar case where Tomcat logs `null` for the request URI when invalid characters are in the request. (Unlike your case, the protocol version is also logged as `null`.)

Answer (score -1):

path is `null` so in postman, your endpoint would be `http://targethost.com/null`